# How can I embed an image in a .pod file to have it render in .odt?

Tags: perl, pandoc, odt

I have a program called *multipandoc* which takes as input a plain-text file in Perl's Plain Old Documentation (.pod) format and converts it simultaneously into .txt, .html, .pdf and .odt formats.  It does so by use of the Pod::Pandoc module from CPAN.

If I wish to embed an image in the .html version of the output, I know that I can say:

```
=begin html

<img src="file:///tmp/images/sector-balances-over-time-sum-to-zero.jpeg">

=end html
```

Does anyone know what the equivalent argument would be for embedding a locally stored image in OpenOffice/LibreOffice output?  That is, I would like to say something like:

```
=begin odt

[PATH TO IMAGE]

=end odt
```

Comment: `.odt` file is a text file, not image [OpenDocument Text Document](https://fileinfo.com/extension/odt).

Comment: If you would like to include html link to local `.odt` file then use `<a href="file:///path/file.odt">{File Description}</a>` instead.

Comment: Browsers can't natively display those. You would need to get some kind JavaScript app that can render it. As software recommendations are off-topic, we must vote to close.

Comment: I'd like to answer this question. He's not asking for software recommendations. It's about writing pod that will translate into the desired output.

Comment: brian d foy is correct.  I'm simply asking for one string to go between the `=begin odt` and `=end odt` tags in the same way I already have for html.